# Are blocked requests by S3 CORS billable?

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

I'm getting a large amount of POST requests to my S3 bucket. 
Ideally I'd like to block them all, so I've been looking into [CORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html). 
If a request is being blocked by the CORS policy, 
do I still pay for it at the end of the month?

Comment: Where do the requests originate from?

Comment: Since I'm using Cloudflare, there's no way to detect the original IP on the S3 logs